# Swiping sidebar away in the SE Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

A wild sidebar appears when I press the triple-line button on the top left. Trying to swipe it away was not very effective. Swiping the sidebar to the left should make it go away. But it doesn't.

Please make the sidebar able to be swiped away. The Running Apps menu has it where you can swipe a process to make it go away, so the sidebar in the app should work similarly.

- App version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Malata
- Device Model: Malata SMBA1002
- The back of the tablet says: ViewSonic gTablet UPC300-2.2
- OS Version: 4.1.2 (eng.G_Harmony.20121202.215512)

Comment: Screenshot will help figure out what going on.